# React.js how to get array from js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm try to get array from a js file to my jsx file how can I do that?

this is my js file, httpservice.js:

```
var urlArray = [];

var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=10&type=gif',
    { form: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
            var xml = body;
            parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
                var responsObj = result.response;
                var dataArrayObj = responsObj.data;
                var dataObj = dataArrayObj[0];

                var imagesArray = dataObj.images;
                var imageObj = imagesArray[0];
                var imageArray = imageObj.image;
                for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
                    var object = imageArray[i];
                    var url = object.url[0];
                    urlArray.push(url);
                    console.log("almoss " + url);
                }
            });
        }
    });
var service ={
  get:function(){
    console.log("making request");
    return urlArray;
  }
};
```

and this is my jsx file, gifurllist.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var GifItem = require('./GifItem.jsx');

var Http = require('../services/httpservice');
var List = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {urlarray:[]};
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    Http.get().then(function(data){
      console.log("data:" + data);
      this.setState({urlarray: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function(){
          var listItems = this.state.urlarray.map(function(item){
      return <GifItem key={item.id} url={item.url} />;
    });
    return(<ul> {listItems}</ul>);
  }
});

module.exports = List;
```

in the  line Http.get().then(function(data) I want to get my urlArray in the data.. 
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try not using then method in componentWillMount and use as below:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
   var data = Http.get();  //this is not returning a promise
                           //so then may not be used

   console.log("data:" + data);
   this.setState({urlarray: data});    
}
```

Comment: yes, but this one now told me that my data array is undefined